# Animated backgrounds on websites

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm interested how are these backgrounds made:

http://www.studioup.it/
https://www.fbf8.com/

I tried searching Google, but i'm not sure how is this technique called. Search for 'animated background' did not give the results what i was hoping for.

Is this some shape drawing / animation or what? Or maybe it's background animation, but done very elegant and with good taste?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there isn't any specific name for this technique

Just applying classes, change positioning based on scroll position.

More details here 
http://css-tricks.com/fancy-scrolling-sites/

There's another similar effect called Parallax Scrolling which is quite popular as well.(except for a few exceptions, I hate it mostly)